# Invalid controller specified (adminlogin)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-controller-router, zend-config

Code for indexAction() in AdminLoginController is:

```
$form_object = new Application_Form_NewProfile();
$form_object->setAction('/adminlogin/index');
$form_object->setMethod('post');
$this->view->form = $form_object;
if($this->getRequest()->isPost())
{
 echo 'Inside event:';
 $login_data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
 if($form_object->isValid($login_data))
 {
       $form_data = $form_object->getValues();

 }


}
```

In Application_Form_NewProfile I have made a form.and in index.phtml I have viewed that form using echo $this->form. When I run the project form appears but when i put the details in form elements such as textfields and then click on button then it says that InvalidController specified(adminlogin) as I have set action of the form in above indexAction() as $form_object->setAction('/adminlogin/index') but its not finding that controller Why??Plz help me out to resolve this issue.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$form_object->setAction($this->view->baseUrl("/adminlogin/index"));
```

Comment: @AbhishekSharma try change your controller name to "admin" or "login" and test again to determine what is the root of error

Comment: @eureka I renamed the controller name from adminlogin to admin and it worked.Thanks.But why this is.Is there any naming convention to be followed?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma I'm not sure about Zend naming convention. Basically, you should read http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.naming-conventions.html. But It is a little bit vague. Or you should ask a new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: For camel-cased controller or action names, Zend rewrites the url by separating the camel-cased names with a hyphen. Eg. if your controller name is 'AdminLoginController' your controller in the url becomes 'admin-login'